# NSPasteboard setString:forType: returns NO under Leopard, fine in Snow Leopard

Tags: objective-c, macos, legacy, osx-leopard, nspasteboard

The following code is from a `NSTableViewDataSource` where I'm trying to impliement drag and drop.

Can someone tell me why the `setString:forTypes:` method in the following code returns `NO` under Leopard? It works fine in Snow Leopard. I checked the "*Pasteboard Programming Topics for Cocoa*" legacy document but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard
{
    NSString *str;
    if ([tableView isEqualTo:databaseView]) {
        str = [[commander databases] objectAtIndex:[rowIndexes firstIndex]];
    } else if ([tableView isEqualTo:favouritesView]) {
        str = [[commander favourites] objectAtIndex:[rowIndexes firstIndex]];
    }

    if (str != nil) {
        NSArray *types = [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType];
        [pboard declareTypes:types owner:nil];
        if ([pboard setString:str forType:NSStringPboardType]) {
            return YES;
        } else {
            [self handleErrorString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: Couldn't copy '%@' to pasteboard!", str]];
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wild guess, but check the data:  that `pboard` is not nil, and that `str` is really a string.

Comment: Wow, pboard *was* nil. But what would cause pboard to be nil?

Comment: Good question... maybe the pasteboard gets messed up somewhere else in your app that uses pasteboards?  I don't know.  Maybe you should have upvoted my answer but not accepted it.

Comment: I ran some tests with a relatively blank project and it looks like it's only nil when I use remote debugging. Maybe I should start a new question for this new actual cause of my problem.